# Jenkins and GIT Clarification

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a GIT setup in my AIX server for a java website.

I have setup **Bare** repositories where several developers commit their code and I have several **Non-Bare** repositories hosted in my development server.

I have heard that Jenkins can monitor the changes in GIT-HUB and then run the build process by checking out the latest contents from the GIT-HUB if a new commit is found.

Can I configure Jenkins to monitor my **Bare** and **Non-Bare** repositories in my dev server and start the build process when a new commit is found.

Here both GIT and Jenkins is setup on the same Unix Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as Jenkins has some means of accessing the git repository, it can monitor it and start a build when changes are detected. If Jenkins is on the same server, you should be able to give it the file system path to the repository.

Note that a single job can only monitor a single repository. That is, if you want to monitor multiple repositories, you either need several jobs or some kind of meta-repository that pulls them together. If this is what you need to do, you might want to consider [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin), although it is only in an early alpha stage.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest any good video tutorials for Jenkins.

Comment: A few things come up on youtube when you search for "Jenkins". I'm not aware of a full video tutorial.

Comment: I hope you can always resort to post-commit hook as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook to initiate whatever you need.

Comment: @dmitry_romanov:Thanks for the reply.Could you give an example of how I can refer a local bare repo  located in say /usr/apps/gitrepo in Jenkins.

Comment: @DarkMatter: I would create alias for `push` or `commit` command to trigger the build as described here: https://bitbucket.org/dromanov/testing_ground/wiki/Use%20web-hook%20to%20trigger%20CI%20build%20and%20test