# See git a list of all commits that went between two commits (across branches)

Tags: git

I have two branches where commits are made independently and I would like to run a Git command that will show me all commits that went in between a certain timeframe (expressed as commit hashes) regardless of branch.

This is my test repo for the purpose of demonstration: https://github.com/jsniecikowski/testApp

If we were to imagine Git's history as a list (latest on top):

- 4332e0e on release branch
- 18bc14a on release branch
- 90f9149 on master branch
- 4f6e07f on release branch
- ca404cf on release branch
- 6cf47b3 on release branch

then I would like to say: 'give me all changes that happened between '90f9149' and '4332e0e'.
Ideally I would get one commit: 18bc14a

My understanding is that this command would work:

```
git log --full-index --no-abbrev --format=raw -M -m --raw 90f9149d2f7367738e9d6f4a53c2c325f96a9b5f..4332e0eb24e18119b10835e361915f1f5eff16bc
```

However, this command is returning more results than expected.

Is this a bug with git, or am I missing something in my command?

Comment: You might want to add `--no-merges` to take merges out of the log output.

Comment: This does not change the output of unknown changes. Plus, this mechanism is used for polling for new builds, and I do want to build when a merge is committed.

Comment: Ahhh. So you want to do continuous build/integration. Have you looked at Jenkins or teamcity yet?

Comment: This question is actually a result of debugging the Git plugin for Jenkins, because that's the command it runs to poll for changes. I have a setup described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29780647/jenkins-and-git-monitor-specific-folder-on-any-branch/29788180?noredirect=1#comment47797557_29788180) that does not work as expected.

Comment: Gotcha. For what it's worth, I looked at the log of your `Release` branch, and I see many more commits than 3 between 61641a2 and 18bc14a. https://github.com/jsniecikowski/testApp/commits/Release

Comment: It might be a matter of trying to espect linear results from a non-linear versioning system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauthier's excellent answer was very close but it didn't say how to use hashes for specifying the region we want to check.

Building on top of that I did:

```
git log Build-Release-Testing --since="$(git log -1 90f9149d2f7367738e9d6f4a53c2c325f96a9b5f --pretty=%ad)" --until="$(git log -1 4332e0eb24e18119b10835e361915f1f5eff16bc --pretty=%ad)"
```

The remaining part is to eliminate the specified hashes from the return.

Answer (score 3):

According to the repo you linked to, if you only want 18bc14a as a result, you don't want the commits that differ between `master` and `Release`, but the commits in `Release` that have a later date than the latest commit in `master`. Are you sure about this?

In that case, you can get the date of your latest commit in master with:

```
git log -1 master --pretty=%ad
```

and the commits since a date in Release with:

```
git log Release --since=<date>
```

Putting these together:

```
git log Release --since="$(git log -1 master --pretty=%ad)"
```

This also includes 4332e0e, but why wouldn't you want that? If you really don't, add a `^` after `Release`.