# Openshift - trigger Jenkins build on git push

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I work with Openshift now and I have a problem. 
I created an application server with Jenkins and when I push to the master branch of the git repository the Jenkins build is triggered automatically.
The point is that the build isn't triggered when I push to another branch (not master).

I've read topics like this one ([How to configure Git post commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook)) and I do realize what the ways to make Jenkins build on git push are.

Unfortunately I haven't found any information about how this is done in the Openshift Jenkins. This mechanism is already implemented there and I simply want to replace the trigger from the "master" branch to another one.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the "Configuring Which Branch to Deploy" section from the following page:

https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html#configuring-which-branch-to-deploy

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I didn't find his article when I looked for the solution.