# how to get submodules to trigger a Jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a submodule A that is not a standalone application. It requires the main application for it to work. I would like to create a CI build for A so that whenever a commit is pushed to A it triggers a build with the main project code.

How do I do that in Jenkins?

What I need to do:

- A commit to A triggers a build.
- The build clones the Main project code and pulls the latest code for A at the latest commit for A (not the commit that the Main Project knows about).

How would I do that using Jenkins and GIT?

Note I have multiple submodules for the project. Submodule A triggers a build that pulls the latest changes from A and also the latest of main code and pulls updates from the other submodules.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done without git hooks.  In this example we have 3 repos:

1. parent

   - Empty repo that just has submodules
2. child-a

   - One child submodule repo
3. child-b

   - The other child submodule repo

When cloned with sub-modules it looks like:

```
parent\
    child-a\*
    child-b\*
```

---

In Jenkins create a freestyle project called `dummy-child-a`.

- Under `Source Code Management` setup the `Repository URL` for `child-a`
- Under `Build Triggers` you choose `Poll SCM` and set your desired interval
- Under `Build` click `Add build step`

  - Choose `Execute Windows batch command` or `Execute shell` depending on your OS
  - In the script box do something like `echo hello` (this is the dummy part)

---

Repeat these steps for `child-b`

---

In Jenkins create a freestyle project called `parent`.  This is where we will actually do the building

- Under `Source Code Management` setup the `Repository URL` for `parent`
- Click `add` under `Additional Behaviours` and choose `Advanced sub-modules behaviours`

  - Check:
  - `Recursively update submodules`
  - `Update tracking submodules to tip of branch`
  - `Use credentials from default remote of parent repository`
- Under `Build Triggers` check `Build after other projects are built`

  - In the `Projects to watch` field, fill all projects to watch with comma separation: `dummy-child-a, dummy-child-b`
  - If `parent` doesn't have source code that will change, You don't need to `Poll SCM` on this Jenkins job
  - Check `Trigger even if the build fails`

---

And you're done.  Any changes to either child-a or child-b will trigger a rebuild of parent.  This method assumes that the number of submodules in parent changes infrequently.  If you were to add another submodule you would need to make another `dummy` project, and then update the `projects to watch` of the `parent` Jenkins build.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two steps:

1. Enable a build trigger url on the Jenkins job you want to build. This is done under "Trigger builds remotely" tab. The url will be in the form: `JENKINS_URL/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build?token=TOKEN_NAME`.
2. Setup a git post-receive hook in submodule A that calls the above url. An easy way to do so is simply to use curl: `curl JENKINS_URL/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build?token=TOKEN_NAME`.

A push to submodule A will then trigger the main project Jenkins's job by calling the url. Configure the Jenkins job to update its code before build or any other specifics you need.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook) provides a lot of details on how to setup the git hook.