# How to edit source code in local computer and server simultaneously

Tags: web-deployment

I am a new web developer. I am using XAMPP and Dreamweaver CS6. I want to edit and debug my source code on my local computer. Then I want to commit that edit to my web server (shared or vps). Right now I edit files on local computer and then I upload that file to server.

Can anyone suggest any other options.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could achieve this in many ways.

For example you can use deployment tools (like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)) and then configure it to hook your commits. In order to do this you need first to install [Git](https://git-scm.com/) in your system (I'm not sure but maybe you can even find some Git plugins for Dreamweaver so that you could work with Git directly from Dreamweaver; if not don't worry there are plenty of Git clients that help to facilitate use of Git, [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is one of them)

If you feel like you have difficulty in configuring Jenkins to hook your commits I'd suggest you to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12794930/2568469).

Comment: Thank you, Stephanie and Hatef.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Dreamweaver in forever but you can upload on saving which you set in the Site Definition.  Go to the Remote definition that you setup and click on the Advanced tab.  You can set DW to automatically upload on save there. It's generally not best practice but it's an option.