# SetupAngularJS or Angular2 Projects for Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment

Tags: angularjs, git, angular, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

Currently I have my git set up for AngularJS Projects. I do testing locally and if the tests pass I commit the code to Git repo. What I want to do is set up the UI project with CI and CD such that even after testing locally when I commit the code to Git repo it should trigger tests and then build (for Angular2 or minify for example for AngularJS) the project ready to be used. If the tests fail it should reject the push/changes. It should then push the passed code to the appropriate deployment folder automatically.

Can Grunt/Gulp do this or I need some other CI/CD apps/tools for this. If so can someone explain how to set this up?

Comment: Do you want to leverage external CI tool like Travis CI?

Comment: Preferably internal tool deployment. IT Policy restrictions here.

Comment: You could leverage tools like Jenkins but you need to create a project in it and configure the actions to execute to build / test your project. Is it for an Angular2 project?

Comment: Yes sir, it is for Angular2. Right now we are building the JS locally

Comment: Okay great! Do you use karma to execute your tests?

Comment: Yes Karma, Grunt/Gulp and Jasmine

Comment: This question could interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook.

Comment: Can I use the same concept to trigger Karma, Grunt from Jenkins after a commit has been done? Can I not watch a repository for changes from Grunt and then get execute the next steps. Is that possible or I am yapping?