# Attaching Grunt tasks to Git hooks like Git pre-push to deploy to production after tests

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, gruntjs

I am searching the net for CD of Git repos to production directly using grunt. Has anyone tried attaching tests and deployment to production on passing tests using Grunt in the server?

My previous general question lead me to Jenkins. Just wondering if the above attachment is possible and any Gruntfile examples
[SetupAngularJS or Angular2 Projects for Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549335/setupangularjs-or-angular2-projects-for-continuous-integration-and-continuous-de)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-githooks

Comment: I don't use githooks in my projects but almost all of them deploy using Grunt.  I simply stage my tests prior to actual deployment tasks; if the tests fail then grunt won't move onto the next task

Comment: How do you capture the results of the test? In a logfile?