# Jenkins git commit notification configuration

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I use [How to configure Git post commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook) from gitlab to notify Jenkins of a new commit like:

```
https://jenkins.company.com/git/notifyCommit?url=project:Project.git
```

which works just fine.

However, if the test cases do not fail on `master branch` I want to release a new version (git tag & change some version in a file & **push**). **This re-triggers the aforementioned webhook.**

Is it possible to have Jenkins only re-trigger the build if built by a certain user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now this will be our solution

stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm
    echo "My branch is: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    echo "GIT commit is:"
    sh ' git log -1'
    // Jenkins does not support it any better: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133
    sh 'git log -1 --pretty=%aE > commandResult'
    result = readFile('commandResult').trim()
    if("jenkins@faktorzehn.at" == result){
      echo 'STOP pipeline to prevent infinite loop'
      error 'STOP to prevent infinite loop'
    }

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should separate the development branch and the master branch? I.e. have developer push commits to `develop`, set Jenkins to build `develop` and push to `master` after testing. This way you should not end up in a build loop (and the separate branch will make it easier to work with tested code).