# I want to configure a job in such a way that it will run every after check in as well as once in a day

Tags: jenkins

I want to configure a job in such a way that it will run when there is code checkin in GIT. The same job will run at least once in a day if there is no code check in on that day even i.e. weekend OR holiday

Answer (score 1):

Set up an Git hock to trigger the job (or poll SCM for changes), [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook). Then in the job configuration add a Build Trigger of type `Build periodically`:

[image]