# Set gitea commit status with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, commit, gitea

I want to set the commit status on my gitea server after a build in jenkins.

Gitea has the endpoint for that, but in my build steps I don't see the option for that. Also, I have already installed gitea plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gitea+Plugin)

Has anyone figure out how to setup this in jenkins?

[image]

[image]

Update: Added screenshot with the gitea communication error[image]

Comment: Considering the Gitea communication error: see following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647936/11993501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it. [Gitea-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitea-plugin) allows you to create a new kind of job. You have to configure your gitea server in Jenkins-> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.

After that you only have to create a new job of kind Gitea Organization. This will do all work without setting nothing more.

I recommend too, setting up [Gitea webhook to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48316346/gitea-and-jenkins-webhook)

Comment: I already tried to add my gitea server in configure system but I'm always get a communicate error (403/Forbidden), my server is secured(https) and I configured the token properly (If I remove the token I get a 401, that is logic). So, I have no clue what is happening. I will add a screenshot to the main post

Comment: This plugin is bad/not documented. I don't remember where but I read that you have to use an admin user in your configuration. I create a new admin (service) user just for jenkins in Gitea and configure it with it.
![jenkins config](https://imgur.com/a/yr9hurf).

Comment: Did you try using user and pass instead of token?