# How to connect Jenkins and Gieta

Tags: jenkins, certificate, webhooks, gitea

I have the problem, that I want to establish a CI/CD Pipeline between my Gitea Repo and Jenkins. So far I created a webhook with the Gitea API to Jenkins. 
Unfortunatly, when I try to send test packages from Gitea to Jenkins, I get the x509 Error, saying that the Certificates are not valid

> Delivery: Post https://*************/jenkins: x509: certificate is valid for xxxxxxxxxxxxx, not yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

On the other Hand I cant add my gitea Server in the Jenkins web UI. If I try to do so, I receive an error saying that The connection cannot be established because:

> Could not communicate with server: HTTP 403/Forbidden

I am quite desperate by now. I already tried to add Certs to the machine Jenkins is running on, to eliminate the x509 error, but it didnt help. 
Also if I try to add instead of my server the official try.gitea.io Server, it actually works. But I nedd my server in the config, so it´s not optional to use the official one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I use Jenkins Version 2.190.2 runnin in Docker container with Gitea Plugin Version 1.1.2.

I see the same problem with the message

> Could not communicate with server: HTTP 403/Forbidden

in

> Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Gitea Servers

when I set the Server URL to a Gitea server with the https protocol (e.g. Server URL: `https://gitea.mycompany.com` and Name: mycompany_gitea)

I have tried to add the certificate of `gitea.company.com` to the trusted certificates of the Jenkins JVM by means of the keytool, but no success (consider the ssl certificate of `gitea.company.com` is a globally trusted certificate and not a locally generated or private certificate).

In the end I tried to add new Gitea Organization Folder by

> Jenkins > New Item > Gitea Organization (with name e.g. mycompany)

despite the problem message.

I configured the new Gitea Organization project under 'Gitea Organization' with following values:

- Server: mycompany_gitea
- Credentials: (Jenkins credential of a Gitea user with access to all Gitea/git repositories)
- Owner: (Gitea organisation/user name)

and... Ta-dah! It works! I can without any problems Scan the Gitea Organization now.

Thus it seems the message

> Could not communicate with server: HTTP 403/Forbidden

is a kind of "false positive" and can be ignored...

---

Considering the message

> Delivery: Post https://*************/jenkins: x509: certificate is valid for xxxxxxxxxxxxx, not yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

I had the same error by the integration with Jenkins. The problem was that Gitea does not support the "certificate discovery" feature (as for example a browser like Firefox does, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587851/openssl-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-for-experian-url/7644229#7644229)) and Jenkins was misconfigured and was sending only the end entity certificate.

After making Jenkins to send the entire certificate chain, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

according to Jenkins gitea plugin document :

`Hint: you can ignore a "HTTP 403/Forbidden" error here in case your gitea instance is private.`

more information : https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitea/