# Adding Gitea server URL in Jenkins reports 403 forbidden

Tags: jenkins, gitea

I install the Gitea plugin for Jenkins and try to add Gitea server in Configuration
[image: Add Gitea Server to Jenkins]

My Gitea URL:

[image: Gitea URL]

But I get HTTP 403/Forbidden warning.

I find a similar question: [How to connect Jenkins and Gieta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672300/how-to-connect-jenkins-and-gieta/58647936#58647936)
And I don't know clearly how to "make Jenkins to send the entire certificate chain" at the end of that  answer, if this way works.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine as official documentation says-
Hint: you can ignore a "HTTP 403/Forbidden" error here in case your gitea instance is private.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitea/