# Automatic pull request merge in Gitea upon successful Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, gitea

I want to configure `Gitea` and `Jenkins`, so `Gitea` would automatically merge pull requests upon successful build in Jenkins.

What's the least effort way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Gitea API to merge a pull request, the API docs are [here](https://try.gitea.io/api/swagger#/repository/repoMergePullRequest).

As the last step in Jenkins, call the Gitea API via `curl` to merge the PR.

Answer (score 3):

For me the best solution was to use the [Gitea Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitea) despite it is poor documented.

Some useful functions:

- sync of structures/organazations/repositories
- push webhooks
- PRs from origin
- PRs from forks

Here you can find more information:

- [Initial Setup](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitea-plugin/tree/master/docs)
- [Configuring webhooks in Jenkins](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/3724)
- [Configuration hints](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/issues/1631)
- [Configuration example as youtube video](https://youtu.be/B4boQozMaRA)
- [Configuration of webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231224/11993501)

Answer (score 1):

It should be generally available with [this pull request](https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/pull/9307)